# Python str.count doesn't return values

Tags: pandas, string, count

This is my line:

```
df['VN_J'] = df['Vote_Now'].str.count("JD(U)")
```

But Results are false even if string in dataframe matches `JD(U)`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you are passing to `str.count` is actually interpreted as a regular expression.  Therefore, since `(` and `)` are both regex *metacharacters*, they need to be escaped here:

```py
df['VN_J'] = df['Vote_Now'].str.count(r'JD\(U\)')
```